# Bash script for creating default user in docker MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, ubuntu

I am developing a "one file script" for run MySQL database inside Docker and many useful thinks. The script should create a container with MySQL and after that create a new user with maximum privileges.

The problem occurs when I try to connect to MySQL command line from the **bash script**. Part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysqlContainerName=project-mysql
mysqlRootUsername=root
mysqlRootPassword=root_pass
mysqlUsername=db_user
mysqlPassword=db_pass
mysqlDb=project_db

echo -e "Creating container \e[31m$mysqlContainerName\e[0m"
docker run --rm -d \
  --name=$mysqlContainerName \
  --network api-network \
  -p 3306:3306 \
  -v /opt/docker-data/mysql-volumes:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$mysqlRootPassword \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$mysqlDb \
  -t mysql:8.0.19

docker exec $mysqlContainerName \
  mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --protocol=tcp \
  -uroot -p$mysqlRootPassword -e "CREATE USER '$mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 
'$mysqlPassword';"
```

So, container successfully created, but all the time I get an error message: ***ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)***
Any suggestions?

Comment: `set -e` so that the script exits if there’s an error starting the container.  Double-quote all of those `”$environmentVariables”`, especially the password ones that are likely to contain punctuation.  Just use the `mysql` client on the host rather than `docker exec`, or better, use the functionality built into the stock `mysql` image to create the initial user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a few hours of searching, I found a solution.
Added ***bash -c*** parameter and in *quotes* connection to MySQL and query.

```
docker exec $mysqlContainerName bash -c "mysql -h172.21.0.1 -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u$mysqlRootUsername -p$mysqlRootPassword -e \"CREATE USER '$mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$mysqlPassword';\"; exit;"
```